# Why JQuery isn't appending HTML to DOM

Tags: jquery, handlebars.js

So I'm trying to use handlebars and jquery to handle some DOM manipulation after an AJAX call.

I have something like this:

```
<script id="answers-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
<td>
    <tr id="detail-{{userId}}">
      <td colspan="100">
        <table id="itemList" class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr id="head" class="dataRow">
                    <th class="cenas">cenas</th>
                    <th class="coisas">coisas</th>
                    <th class="bicho">bicho</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {{> templateDetailsItem}}
            </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
</td>
</script>
<script id="template-details-item" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
{{#each responses}}
    <tr id="{{id}}">
        <td>{{nome_contacto}}</td>
        <td>{{numero_contacto}}</td>
        <td>{{preco}}</td>
    </tr>
{{/each}}
</script>
```

And JavaScript:

```
const answersOfUser = {
    userId: itemId,
    responses: response
};
Handlebars.registerPartial("templateDetailsItem", $("#template-details-item").html());
const template = Handlebars.compile($("#answers-template").html());
$('table#itemList tbody td')
    .append(template(answersOfUser));
```

But nothing happens. Not even an error.

As far I can tell Handlebars is working fine because this `console.log(template(answersOfUser))` gives me a string with the full html I want appended.

The string given is in multi line without any escape chars. Could this be it?

What's wrong with my approach?

Comment: Add `console.log($('table#itemList tbody td').length)` and see if the jQuery selector is finding the element in question.

Comment: That is not the issue because if I do this `$('table#itemList tbody td').append('something')` it works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was eventually able to figure out. There was a mix of issues. Returns don't seem that well accepted by jquery append or after, also I had an issue with the table. Just would like jquery would give some kind of error instead of empty everything.

praise @Ben Osborne for pointing me in right direction.

Template:

```
    <script id="answers-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <tr id="detail-{{userId}}">
        <td colspan="100">
            <table id="itemList" class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr id="head" class="dataRow">
                        <th class="cenas">cenas</th>
                        <th class="coisas">coisas</th>
                        <th class="bicho">bicho</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {{> templateDetailsItem}}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</script>
<script id="template-details-item" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    {{#each responses}}
    <tr id="{{id}}">
        <td>{{nome_contacto}}</td>
        <td>{{numero_contacto}}</td>
        <td>{{preco}}</td>
    </tr>
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

JS:

```
const answersOfUser = {
    userId: itemId,
    responses: response
};
Handlebars.registerPartial("templateDetailsItem", $("#template-details-item").html());
const template = Handlebars.compile($("#answers-template").html());
const htmlTemplate = template(answersOfUser);
$(that).parent().parent().after(htmlTemplate.replace(/[\r\n]/g, ''));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are the things I think you need to fix:

- In  answers-template, you have a tr inside of a td.  You need to wrap the rows with a table.
- When you use .append, it looks like you're appending a td to another td.  I think you'll want to append the td to a tr of itemList.

[Here's a working jsFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/OsborneSupremacy/27j3wfo2/6/)

```
const template = Handlebars.compile($("#answers-template").html());
$('table#itemList > tbody > tr')
  .append(template(answersOfUser));
```

It's not working completely (the answers are not getting bound to the details template), but the template is at least getting appended to the DOM.

Comment: I want a nested table, but to reduce code in here (SO) I trimmed somethings so it does not make so much sense as it is now. That part is right.
The right code would be: `$(that).parent().after(template(answersOfUser)`, but I wanted to simplify here
You are close, though, with the white space, but it seems that you are striping to many things. I get only the last tags levels. the <td> with the values of responses.

Comment: Ahh... It looks like whitespace wasn't the issue.  Don't know why I thought that.  I will update my answer and the fiddle.

Comment: I'm seeing that it is removing too much white space. it removing white space inside the tags xD

Comment: Could that be because there's no stylesheet?  With the updated jsFiddle, I'm not longer doing any removing or trimming.